Why taking ln() of change in invested wealth? Methodology of a published paper
I am going through the paper referenced below, and I am struggling to understand the reasoning behind the equation to calculate their dependent variable. Please could you help me with that?
Paper of reference: https://epub.uni-regensburg.de/54281/9/2023-05%20Sebastian-Noth-Grafe_Commission-Ban.pdf
(i.e., paper is called 'The Effect of Commission Bans on Household Wealth: Evidence from OECD Countries', by: Sebastian et al.)
dependent variable (see table 1): "the approximate performance of invested money of all private
households". They "use the intuitive definition of invested money by assuming that investments
happen at the end of the period." Therefore, they "extract the wealth gain less savings (i.e.,
household wealth development less currency, deposits and savings in relation to household
assets)."
Return_on_invested_wealth = ln(Change_invested_wealth)-Saving_as_%_of_household_income -1
I am wondering why are they taking the change of invested wealth and not the change in saving rate too?
And why are they taking the ln of change_invested_wealth?

Why not ask the authors? Or raise the question in an economics forum?

The question isn't self-contained -- you're asking or expecting us to read the paper -- and in any case isn't a matter of statistical expertise or experience.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
